# Libtool output "unknown option character -o" error

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, static-libraries, libtool

So I have a directory of .o files that I am trying to output to a static library using libtool.

From inside the directory containing all the .o files I do the following, where mylibrary.a is located in the parent directory

```
$ libtool  -static *.o -output ../mylibrary.a
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
unknown option character `o' in: -output
```

How do I resolve this? I am doing this all on the mac osx terminal

Answer (score 7):

The flag should be `-o`, not `-output`.